# AutoMapper with Domain model

Tags: automapper

I am new for AutoMapper

I have following domain Model.

```cs
public class Contact
{
    public string University { get; set; }

    public string GraduationYear { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to change domain model and would like to add extra attribute for GraduationYear property.

I have created attribute class on my mvc 4 project

```cs
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class Mapping : System.Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Used above attribute on class named 'ContactMapping' Created

```cs
public class ContactMapping
{
    [Telephony.Helper.Attribute.Mapping(Name = "Graduate")]
    public string GraduationYear { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting contact object from domain service which doesn't have custom attribute 'Mapping'.

```cs
var contact = new ContactService().Get(contactPredicate).Single();
```

Now i am doing Auto Mapper

```cs
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Telephony.Helper.Mapping.ContactMapping, Aurora.CustomersMvc.Domain.Contact>();

    var test = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Aurora.CustomersMvc.Domain.Contact>(contact);
    var contactwithCustomAttr = contact.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => ((Telephony.Helper.Attribute.Mapping[])p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Telephony.Helper.Attribute.Mapping), false))
                .Any(attr => attr.ToString() == "Graduate"));
```

I am getting contactwithCustomAttr.Count() zero. I am expecting to return GraduationYear property as mapper should apply my custom property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: I don't think that you were properly mapping

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Aurora.CustomersMvc.Domain.Contact, Telephony.Helper.Mapping.ContactMapping>();

var test = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Aurora.CustomersMvc.Domain.Contact, Telephony.Helper.Mapping.ContactMapping>(contact);
var contactwithCustomAttr = test.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => ((Telephony.Helper.Attribute.Mapping[])p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Telephony.Helper.Attribute.Mapping), false))
            .Any(attr => attr.Name == "Graduate"));
```

Comment: contactwithCustomAttr return null

Comment: still return null. test variable having only single property.

Comment: Is Mapping (AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Aurora) return only common proprties?

Comment: Edited it again. You had an issue with attr.ToString() == "Graduate", it should be attr.Name == "Graduate"